# Why does this dplyr filter not work in shiny, but works fine when run without shiny?

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, shiny, conditional-statements

The below code, run without Shiny, works fine for grouping data by 2 different methods of measuring time horizons (by calendar month ("Period_1") and by months elapsed since element origination ("Period_2")), and for expanding the data frame to true-up periods when grouping by Period_2:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,2,2,2,2),
    Period_1 = c("2020-03", "2020-04", "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-04"),
    Period_2 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4),
    ColA = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 52),
    ColB = c(15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 87)
    )

### Expand the dataframe to including missing rows ###
    dataExpand <- 
      data %>%
        tidyr::complete(ID, nesting(Period_2)) %>%
        tidyr::fill(ColA, ColB, .direction = "down")

### Run the expanded data frame through grouping code ###

  # Group by calendar month (Period_1)
    groupData_1 <- 
      dataExpand %>%
      group_by(Period_1) %>%
      select("ColA","ColB") %>%
      summarise(across(everything(), sum)) %>%
      filter(!is.na(Period_1)) # << Add this code to delete NA row for calendar period
      
  # Group by vintage month (Period_2)  
    groupData_2 <- 
      dataExpand %>%
      group_by(Period_2) %>%
      select("ColA","ColB") %>%
      summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Results (which are correct when running the above code):

```
> groupData_1
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Period_1  ColA  ColB
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-01     30    35
2 2020-02     40    45
3 2020-03     60    70
4 2020-04     72   112

> groupData_2
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Period_2  ColA  ColB
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1        1    40    50
2        2    60    70
3        3    70    80
4        4    72   112
```

However, when I throw the above into Shiny where the user can click on the radio button to select grouping by either Period_1 or Period_2, the App crashes. The problem appears to lie in the line `if(input$grouping == 'Period_1'...` because when I comment it out the App runs (but without removing the Period_1's that are NA like this line is suppose to do). How can this be fixed?

```
   library(shiny)
   library(tidyverse)
        
   ui <-
     fluidPage(
       h3("Data table:"),
       tableOutput("data"),
       h3("Sum the data table columns:"),
       radioButtons(
         inputId = "grouping",
         label = NULL,
         choiceNames = c("By period 1", "By period 2"),
         choiceValues = c("Period_1", "Period_2"),
         selected = "Period_1",
         inline = TRUE
       ),
       tableOutput("sums")
     )
        
   server <- function(input, output, session) {
     data <- reactive({
       data.frame(
         ID = c(1,1,2,2,2,2),
         Period_1 = c("2020-03", "2020-04", "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-04"),
         Period_2 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4),
         ColA = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 52),
         ColB = c(15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 87)
       )
     })
          
     dataExpand <- reactive({
       data() %>%
       tidyr::complete(ID, nesting(Period_2)) %>%
       tidyr::fill(ColA, ColB, .direction = "down")
     })  
          
     summed_data <- reactive({
       dataExpand() %>%
         group_by(!!sym(input$grouping)) %>%
         select("ColA","ColB") %>%
         summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE)) #%>%
 
         # Below removes Period_1 rows that are added due to Period_2 < 4 when grouping by Period_2
         if(input$grouping == 'Period_1'){filter(!is.na(Period_1))}
          })
          
     output$data <- renderTable(data())
     output$sums <- renderTable(summed_data())
   }
        
   shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: OP, could this be a masking issue?  I've found that when I load some packages, `dplyr::filter()` is apparently masked by other packages.  Consequently, whenever I use `filter()`, I explicitly call the function from `dplyr`.  Do you still get the same issue if you do that?  In other words, try: `if(input$grouping == 'Period_1'){dplyr::filter(!is.na(Period_1))}`

Comment: chemdork123, that doesn't solve the issue in this case. However I'll remember this possible solution when running into problems in the future. I had not considered masking issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this closer to what you need?

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <-
  fluidPage(
    h3("Data table:"),
    tableOutput("data"),
    h3("Sum the data table columns:"),
    radioButtons(
      inputId = "grouping",
      label = NULL,
      choiceNames = c("By period 1", "By period 2"),
      choiceValues = c("Period_1", "Period_2"),
      selected = "Period_1",
      inline = TRUE
    ),
    tableOutput("sums")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      ID = c(1,1,2,2,2,2),
      Period_1 = c("2020-03", "2020-04", "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-04"),
      Period_2 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4),
      ColA = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 52),
      ColB = c(15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 87)
    )
  })
  
  dataExpand <- reactive({
    data() %>%
      tidyr::complete(ID, nesting(Period_2)) %>%
      tidyr::fill(ColA, ColB, .direction = "down")
  })  
  
  choice <- reactive(input$grouping)
  
  summed_data <- reactive({
    dataExpand() %>%
      group_by(across(choice())) %>%
      select("ColA","ColB") %>%
      summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE)) |> 
      filter(across(1,.fns = ~ .x |> negate(is.na)() ))
    
    # Below removes Period_1 rows that are added due to Period_2 < 4 when grouping by Period_2
    
  })
  
  
  
  output$data <- renderTable(data())
  output$sums <- renderTable(summed_data())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Bruno. Works fine, obrigado! Though I had to change the "|>" in your post to "%>%" to get it to work. To help me remember: "across(1..."  specifies the column to operate on (column 1 in this case) and the second argument, .fns, is the function to apply to that column 1. Please correct me if I am wrong!! (Negate is also new to me, I am studying it now).

Comment: Yes that is right, I was just lazy to create an if cause... the |> operator depends on R being newer that 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Your `summed_data` block doesn't return anything.

```r
summed_data <- reactive({
  dataExpand() %>%
    group_by(!!sym(input$grouping)) %>%
    select("ColA","ColB") %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    # Below removes Period_1 rows that are added due to Period_2 < 4 when grouping by Period_2
    if(input$grouping == 'Period_1'){ filter(!is.na(Period_1)) }
})
```

In fact should be failing with an error.

```r
input <- list(grouping = "Period_2")
mtcars %>%
  if (input$grouping == "Period_1") filter(cyl == 4L)
# Warning in if (.) F else filter(is.na(cyl)) :
#   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
# Error in if (.) F else filter(is.na(cyl)) : 
#   argument is not interpretable as logical
```

One way to fix that would be

```r
mtcars %>%
  { if (input$grouping == "Period_1") filter(., cyl == 4) else .; }
```

Done there:

1. wrapped in braces `{ ... }`;
2. used the special `.` in the call to `filter`, so that it actually has data to operate on; and
3. added an `else` that returns all data otherwise.

Another method:

```r
mtcars %>%
  filter(input$grouping != "Period_1" | cyl == 4L)
```

Notes:

1. Note that I **inverted the logic**. That is, your logic is to filter only if grouping is Period_1; here, `input$grouping != "Period_1"` returns `TRUE` when it is not Period_1, which means nothing in `cyl == 4` will matter, all will be true; if it *is* Period_1, then that will return false, and then `cyl == 4` will have an impact.

The other problem with your code is that you process the pipe `data_Expand() %>% ... summarize(.)` but because you do not capture that expression into a variable, it is never used. Like many things in R (including functions and reactive blocks), the last expression evaluated will be the return value (or whatever is in the explicit `return(.)` call, though often not required). In your case, the `if` statement is evaluated last. If the condition is true, then it tries to run `filter(!is.na(Period_1))`, but that has no data (it is not expressly in the pipe); if the condition is false, since there is no `else` block, it returns `NULL` (invisibly).

Try changing that block to:

```r
summed_data <- reactive({
  dataExpand() %>%
    group_by(!!sym(input$grouping)) %>%
    select("ColA","ColB") %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    filter(input$grouping != "Period_1" | !is.na(Period_1))
})
```